# EF Core lambda expr inside include not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to "translate" one of my SQL queries to EF Core. I have already got it for the base query, but I'm now struggling with the marked line:

[image]

I have tried it this way, but got this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.

How should I correct it?

Thanks.

```
return DataContext.Provks
            .Include(p => p.Company)
            .Include(p => p.Plant)
            .Include(p => p.ProvkDetails.GroupBy(d => d.ProvkId).Select(d => d.Max(d => d.Version)))
            .Where(p => p.PlantId == plantId && p.Year == year)
            .OrderBy(p => p.Created)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Basically by querying what you need *without* using `Include`.

Answer (score 0):

`Include` introduced not for joins but for loading related entities. If you want to mimic SQL - write that in the same way.

```cs
var details = 
   from d in DataContext.Provks
   group d by d.ProvkId into g
   select new 
   {
       ProvkId = g.Key,
       maxVer = g.Max(x => x.Version)
   };

var query = 
   from p in DataContext.Provks
   join d in details on p.ProvkId equals d.ProvkId into dj
   from d in dj.DefaultIfEmpty()
   where p => p.PlantId == plantId && p.Year == year
   order by p.Created
   select new 
   {
      // choose needed fields
   }
```